# Binary makes use of insecure API(s). Need official reports for it's Audit for Xamarin

Tags: .net, security, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We got Penetration tested for our application build in Xamarin.iOS by one of our important Clients and we got the analysis that our "Binary makes use of insecure API(s)".

I have got it investigated and came to Conclusion that it is Xamarin.iOS which is using these functions at low level runtime. It is even giving this analysis for an empty project created in Xamarin.iOS.

I got some information about it on link below that Xamarin.iOS has been audited in past and got it correct for the usage of these functions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/525762/cyber-security-issues-ipa-binary-code-analysis-in.html

However we would need an official evidence for this Audit or an Official statement to be given to Client so that we can get it though. Can we Get some official documentation or any reports of this audit stating that the use of these InSecure functions and APIs are from Xamarin.iOS side and are proved correct?

I can be anytime reached out at my email id for any queries.

Looking for a positive acknowledgement. Thank you.

[Binary Analysis Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LISZY.png)

Comment: you need to contact Microsoft, not SO